# Install Local spark on OSX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to run my Scala job on my local machine (a MacBook pro `osx10.13.3`) and I am having an error at runtime.

My versions:

- scala: `2.11.12`
- spark: `2.3.0`
- hadoop: `3.0.0`

I installed everything through `brew`.

The exception is:

`Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2`

Happening at those line:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName(getName)
  .setMaster("local[2]")
val context = new SparkContext(conf)
```

The last line is where the exception is thrown.

My theory is that `Hadoop` and `spark` version arent working together but I can't find online what version should `Hadoop` be for `spark 2.3.0`.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need Hadoop to run Spark, but Hadoop 2.7 or later is what the  documentation says. Also, `spark-shell` loads these for you, so where are you running this code?

Comment: are u trying to run in spark shell or as an application.If its spark shell its all ready got the spark context, you do not have to declare it.If not please paste the entire code

Comment: 1) Does simple rdd operation through spark-shell work?  2) Provide invocation line of your spark application submit 3) The stacktrace would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out my problem.

So first, yes, I don't need Hadoop installed. Thanks for pointing that out. 
And second I had java10 installed instead of java8. Removing it solved the rest of the problems.

Thank you everyone !